# Rails 4.2.1 Action mailer not delivering the emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, sendmail, actionmailer

Actionmailer does not seem to deliver my emails, my app is in production environment. I have the following set in my config/environments/production.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'noreply@domain.com'}
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'http://domain.com' }
```

Sending the mail

```
UserMailer.welcome(self).deliver_now
```

Rails version: 4.2.1

In my production.log displays no errors, all tasks are completed and it displays the actual mail output in the log.

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
     :port => 587,
     :user_name => "your mail",
     :password => "your password",
     :authentication => :plain,
     :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: This does work, technically not the solution I wanted because I want to use sendmail and not smtp, but this is still correct and lead me to solving my own problem aswell, so thanx! :)